# clone a grafana setup to a different server

Tags: ubuntu, server-setup, grafana

I'm writing a set of scripts to automatically setup any virgin ubuntu server to be in a state usable for my production environment.

One of the things I want to do is setup grafana so that, on install, it has already added prometheus as a datasource, has a dashboard setup, and any other configuration steps already done, without having to touch the graphical interface.

For that, I thought I could set up grafana in a development server, and save the entire configuration directories in gitlab, to copy that configuration into any new server.

Is this something that can be done? And, which directories should I save in version control to completely copy the local grafana setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana saves all of it's configuration (dashboards, panels, users etc.) in a database. By default it is a local sqlite3 database (this can be changed, check `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` file, `[database]` section).

To migrate Grafana instance you would have to dump it's database to a file, and then recreate database from this file. Information how to do this is available in [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#converting_an_entire_database_to_an_ascii_text_file).

Other than that, you would also have to copy `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` config file, if you made any changes to the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying grafana directories, you should take a look at [Provisioning Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/). This is the supported method to automate Grafana provisioning, by creating Data Sources, Dashboards, etc...